# is a flat file imported into Ocacle never going to be relational?

Tags: oracle, informatica, flat-file

I imported a csv flat file into Oracle via IICS. I did this with the intention of running a router function in IICS on the newly created Oracle table, to route rows with different data to different tables also in Oracle. But I was unable to preform the router function. Is this because, a flat file, imported into Oracle, will still forever be a flat file, and therefore never be relational?

Answer (score 0):

When you say imported a csv flat into oracle means you loaded csv file into oracle table. Or flat file acted as Oracle table in IICS?.  Ideally you should import csv flat file into IICS as CSV file (source definition). Then you can use router transformation based on some filter logic like bad or good records.

Comment: I originally set up a mapping connecting IICS to a csv, but I found I couldn't preform a routing transformation. I assumed this was because it was a flat file. So I moved the csv, via IICS, into Oracle, creating an Oracle table. And I tried to preform a routing transformation on that newly created Oracle table. But again, no dice.

Comment: I finally gave up and preformed the routing task in IICS using a pre-existing Oracle table, and that was immediately doable. So I can only assume you either can't preform a routing task on a flat file in IICS, or you need to preform some kind of expression transformation on the flat file, or formerly flat file, in IICS, before attempting the preform a routing transformation.

Comment: I still did not get your object of using route transformation using csv file source.

Comment: It's actually just to learn how to use routing transformation. But the routing was on a table with retail prices. I was trying to route different price point ranges to different new tables that were being creating in Oracle, by IICS, on the fly. This worked fine once I used a pre-existing Oracle table as a source. It wouldn't work on the Oracle table that had been imported from a csv file.